# Data constructor error when implementing state monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm going through the state monad [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more) and I'm trying to implement:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.State

type Stack = [Int]

pop :: State Stack Int
pop = State $ (x : xs) -> (x, xs)
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
"Data constructor not in scope:
    State :: ([t0] -> (t0, [t0])) -> State Stack Int
Perhaps you meant one of these:
    ‘StateT’ (imported from Control.Monad.State),
    variable ‘state’ (imported from Control.Monad.State)"
```

Am I missing something basic here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you aren't. The tutorial <s>is simplifying things a bit (or maybe it is just outdated - I don't go far back enough to know which of the two</s>) is outdated. `Control.Monad.State` defines a monad *transformer* [`StateT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT). It also exports a simpler type synonym equivalent to what the tutorial is teaching you

```
type State s a = StateT s Identity a
```

However, that does mean that the constructor isn't `State`, it is `StateT` (and it has a generalized signature). Thankfully, you won't need to worry too much about that for now.

- For constructing `State`, you can use the [`state`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:state) function and pretend it has the signature `state :: (s -> (a,s)) -> State s a` (in reality, it has a more general signature - which you come across in error messages).
- For de-constructing `State`, just use [`runState :: State s a -> s -> (a,s)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:runState) instead of pattern matching.

---

From the example you gave:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.State

type Stack = [Int]

pop :: State Stack Int
pop = state $ \(x : xs) -> (x, xs)
```

Comment: Thanks Alec, very clear -- I'm glad I'm not going fussy in my old age!

Comment: [The linked tutorial is out of date, not simplifying things.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.0/docs/Control-Monad-State.html#t:State) There was a time when people worried that transformers layered on `Identity` had a runtime cost compared to defining the corresponding monad directly, and so many libraries (mtl included) would ship both a monad and its transformer. Eventually the code duplication/maintenance burden argument against this won out over the performance argument for it.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you suppose that the interface to `State a` is through a data constructor that wraps a function `s -> (a, s)`? That is a simple way to *implement* State, but you are not provided that interface. Instead, use the constructs provided in [Control.Monad.State](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html).

One simple change is just to use the lower-case `state` function designed for this purpose:

```
pop :: State Stack Int
pop = state $ \(x : xs) -> (x, xs)
```

Alternatively, instead of working with this low-level view of State, you can work with it as a monad through its `put` and `get` functions:

```
pop :: State Stack Int
pop = do
  (x : xs) <- get
  put xs
  return x
```

Comment: She is assuming that interface to `State` because that is what the tutorial says. :/ "The `Control.Monad.State` module provides a newtype that wraps stateful computations. Here's its definition: `newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }`".

Comment: I wonder if a pattern synonym would be advisable, so to export the "illusion" of working with a simpler `State` with a simple interface. Using safe coercions, it should have zero runtime cost, I think. This could be extended to most monad transformers applied to `Identity`.